# Getting a connection from a Sybase datasource in WAS 6.1 fails with message "User name property missing in DriverManager.getConnection"

Tags: jdbc, websphere, sybase, datasource, websphere-6.1

I have a standalone application that needs to connect to a Sybase database via a datasource, I'm trying to connect using getConnection() and get the connection from this **Sybase datasource which is hosted in WAS 6.1**, sadly I'm getting an error JZ004 -> [Sybase(R) jConnect for JDBC(TM) Programmer's Reference: SQL Exception and Warning Messages](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1009784)

JZ004 error message is:
***User name property missing in DriverManager.getConnection(..., Properties)
Action: Provide the required user property.***

As you can see, this is not a connectivity (so we can discard JNDI or lookup problems), but rather a configuration problem. For my Sybase datasource in WAS 6.1 I have set up the proper authentication alias (Component-managed Authentication Alias), and I know the credentials are alright, **"Test Connection" is successful for this datasource.** Somebody had a similar problem and was because of the authentication alias-> http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=39915

Next, I tried calling getConnection() but now **I provided the credentials like getConnection(user, password)... and this time it worked!!!** So I suspect that somehow WAS 6.1 is not picking or taking the authentication info I set in the datasource as mentioned before.

If you think that maybe getConnection(user, password) should be OK for my case, well, that's not the case since I have a requirement to keep the credentials in the server, **the standalone application only needs to know the JNDI information to lookup the datasource.**

Please let me know if have faced a similar problem, or what would you suggest me to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another thread -> [Call to DataSource.getConnection not returning the expected connection,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677079/call-to-datasource-getconnection-not-returning-the-expected-connection) I got an answer that also solved this issue, basically the answer is that an authentication alias won't work for external clients according to the [J2C documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/udat_j2cconnfacdet.html). The workaround is to provide the user and password as custom properties instead of being provided as an authentication alias.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the configured resource, you need to look it up rather than using DriverManager directly:

```
new InitialContext().lookup("myDS");
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but i get the problem mentioned before. The DriverManager exception appears in the actual stack trace.

I added a new question for this case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677079/call-to-datasource-getconnection-not-returning-the-expected-connection